# DELETEing a YouTube watchLater playlist item failing - returning 404

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i have code that deletes an item from my youtube watchLater playlist.  this was working ok up to about two weeks ago - now i'm getting a 404 error from youtube.

here's the sequence of requests and responses (with authentication details stripped, of course):

*get playlist items request:*

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?fields=items/id&part=snippet&playlistId=WLlue5EIJLscoxMgEkEZfq_A

*get playlist items response:*

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "V0xsdWU1RUlKTHNjb3hNZ0VrRVpmcV9BLjU2QjQ0RjZEMTA1NTdDQzY="
  }
 ]
}
```

*delete request:*

> DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?id=V0xsdWU1RUlKTHNjb3hNZ0VrRVpmcV9BLjU2QjQ0RjZEMTA1NTdDQzY=

*delete response:*

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
    "reason": "playlistItemNotFound",
    "message": "Playlist item not found.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "id"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Playlist item not found."
 }
}
```

when i view the playlist via the youtube web site, i can see that the item hasn't been deleted.

the docs for the api indicate that i'm doing everything correctly.  while debugging i noticed that the playlist item id is a base64 encoded string; i get 404 using both the encoded and decoded string.

this issue isn't limited to one particular item; it appears any item i place in my watchLater playlist cannot be deleted.  i don't have any issues deleting items from other playlists; only watchLater is having this problem.

anyone have any idea what's going on?

Edit (Oct 2016): Google have said the Watch Later playlist has been deprecated.  See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history

Comment: Reported issue: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8145

Comment: Just out of curosity, Google provides more support here or on code.google.com ?

Comment: it appears they give both sites equal attention.

Comment: By equal attention, you mean "none" ? :) This is quite sad actually...

Comment: yes.  sad and surprising given the breaking nature of this issue.

Comment: broken for so many people now and it's been more than 2 months. still waiting. can everyone tweet them out to get some attention? it literally appears that they pay no attention to their official apis and bug databases at all. trump will build his wall faster than youtube fixing their official API bugs.

Comment: well it appears to be some good sign. I tweeted and sent email to youtube ceo and in couple hours the defect went from open to "Accepted" status and a project member is assigned to it now. hope this gets fixed soon as i have had many users email me about it. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8145#makechanges

Answer (score 0):

The issue is closed in the google issue tracker:

> Marking this issue as Obsolete as the Watch Later playlist has been deprecated. Please see the Revision History for details: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history

> In addition, requests to retrieve playlist details (playlists.list) or playlist items (playlistItems.list) for a channel's watch history or **watch later playlist now return empty lists**. This behavior is true for the new values, HL and WL, as well as for any watch history or watch later playlist IDs that your API Client may have already stored.