# Youtube API getting Watch Later Playlist

Tags: api, youtube, playlist

as in one answer here:
[Youtube Data API v3 PlaylistItems update not working for Watch Later playlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239503/youtube-data-api-v3-playlistitems-update-not-working-for-watch-later-playlists)

There was a change that I can't use playlistitems.list from YT API v3 to retrive Watch Later and Watch History playlists from my channel:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#september-15-2016

TLDR:

> "Requests to retrieve playlist details (playlists.list) for a channel's watch history or watch later playlist will return an empty list after September 12, 2016. Requests to retrieve playlist items (playlistItems.list) in either of those playlists will also return an empty list after that time. This is true for the new values, HL and WL, as well as for any watch history or watch later playlist IDs that your API Client may have already stored."

Is there any other way to programmatically get my Watch Later playlist other than manual scraping?
(By manual scraping I mean traversing http to login, getting into my playlist and manually parsing DOM to get links and snippets of videos in the list.)

Thanks

Comment: I bed you saw this but still may be helpful https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/4xc8rp/youtubes_api_just_deprecated_getting_data_about_a/ just got into same issue and scrapping my not work because of two factor auth

Answer (score 4):

(Copied from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117301/147507)

> If I was in your position, I'd just work my requirement around it, avoiding this. You can go back to v2 or do some other stuff like scraping the website, but if the YouTube API is explicitly preventing these to be available to third parties, it might seem you could get into legal trouble.

Answer (score -1):

> Note that the v2 API provided separate feeds for a channel's favorite
>   videos, watch history, and watch later playlist. The v3 API uses
>   playlists and playlist items to represent all of these concepts.

From: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/playlists

> You also use the channels.list method to get the playlist IDs for a
>   channel's watch history playlist, watch later playlist, uploaded
>   videos and liked videos. Liked videos are videos that the channel
>   owner rated positively

Comment: It is true that you can retrieve the playlist IDs for your watch history playlist etc., however those values can't be used to either read the content or manipulate it (Example: WL ,or HL) ,or at least i couldn't figure it out how to do that. So your answer seems not to be a solution for the Question.